# Verkürzung von "Höker" zu "Hök"

Tags: etymology, idiom, dialect, colloquial

Mir ist die Bezeichnung *Hök* für einen Händler oder Verkäufer geläufig, meist in Zusammensetzung mit einem für die Branche charakterisierenden Gegenstand, wie zum Beispiel *Schraubenhök* (Eisenwarenhändler, Heimwerkergeschäft) oder *Reifenhök* (Reifenhändler/-werkstatt, siehe [Google-Ergebnisse](https://www.google.de/search?q=reifenh%C3%B6k&nfpr=1)).

Jemand schreibt z.B. im [Bikerforum Franken](http://www.bikerforum-franken.de/thread/7094-sich-%C3%A4rgern-beim-motorrad-putzen/?postID=105409#post105409):

> Kenn ich von meiner Werkstatt so in der Form zum Glück nicht. Auch der
>   Reifenhök hat bei mir sauber gearbeitet.

Nun habe ich gelernt, dass es "eigentlich" [*Höker*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hoeker) heißt und zum *Hök* alleine habe ich online keine Informationen gefunden. Mich interessiert aus reiner Neugier, wie es zu so einer Verkürzung kommt und wo der *Hök* herkomment bzw. geläufig ist.

Ich komme selbst aus Franken, hatte aber bisher nicht den Eindruck, dass es sich beim *Hök* um ein fränkisches Idiom handelt. Andererseits kannte ich den *Höker* bisher nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Ich bin des fränkischen Dialekts nicht (wirklich) mächtig. Aber diese Verkürzung hört sich mehr nach "Szene-Sprache", denn Dialekt an (insbesondere in einem *"Motorrad-Schrauber"* Forum).

Den *Höker* (als veraltet für "Kleinhändler") hast Du ja bereits selbst gefunden.

Hier ist noch eine [weitere Information](https://www.wissen.de/wortherkunft/hoeker) zur möglichen etymologischen Herkunft:

> Höker
>   Kleinhändler mit Verkaufsbude oder Verkaufsstand ♦ aus mndrl. hoeker, mnddt. hoke, hoker „Kleinhändler“; dazu mnddt. hokeboke „Huckepack“ und mhd. hucker „Höker“; vielleicht zu Hucke „Rücken“; ein Höker wäre demnach ein Händler, der gerade nur so viele Waren mit sich führt, wie er auf dem Rücken tragen kann

Der letzte Satz *"der gerade nur so viele Waren mit sich führt, wie er auf dem Rücken tragen kann"* scheint mir eine plausible Erklärung zur Wortherkunft zu liefern.
Das bekannte Verb *"verhökern"* (i.e. *Verkaufen*) ist wohl vom *Höker* abgeleitet.

Comment: Vielleicht war meine Fragestellung etwas unpräzise. Mich interessiert speziell der Übergang von *Höker* zu *Hök*, weniger die Herkunft von *Höker* selbst. Beispielsweise, ob die Verkürzung einem Muster folgt, für das es auch andere Beispiele gibt (mir fallen keine ein). Das könnte ein Hinweise auf den Ursprung/Kontext der Verkürzung geben.

Comment: Dafür zeigen die Fundstellen im Web tatsächlich in Richtung Motorradsprech. Habe noch den Fahrradhök in einem KTM-Forum gefunden.

Comment: @code_onkel Ich glaube nicht wirklich, dass es etwas mit Dialekt zu tun hat.

Comment: @code_onkel ... und ich bin mir auch nicht soo sicher, dass jemand aus z.B. der Gastronomie Branche _"mein Gemüse-/Fleisch- Hök"_ sagen würde. Grundsätzlich ein interessantes Thema. Meine Antwort liefert vielleicht schon mal eine Basis.

Comment: Ich habe deine Kommentare zur Frage gelöscht, nachdem Du ja eine(übrigend ganz schöne)  Antwort geschrieben hast. Informationen aus Kommentaren sollen sämtlich in die Antworten (oder Frage) eingepflegt werden, damit spätere Besucher alle wichtigen Informationen gleich finden können.